# Working with interfaces for domain classes and generic services in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

What I would like to achieve is to use interfaces for domain classes and generic types for service layer and be able to change the implementation of the persistence layer from current which is MongoDb to e.g. JPA. Interfaces for domain classes are necessary because of e.g different annotations for JPA and MongoDB (`@Entity` and `@Document`).

Let's look at the structure of the following demo project:

[image]

For each element of the domain model there can be three interfaces, let's explain it using the `user` package:

`User` - representation of domain object

`UserDao` - providing persistence layer methods

`UserService` - providing business logic methods

Here are interfaces for each of them:

```
    public interface User {

        String getId();

        String getFirstName();

        String getLastName();

        List<Consent> getConsents();

        Boolean getBlocked();
    }
```

```
    public interface UserDao <UserType extends User> {

        UserType save(UserType user);

        Optional<UserType> getById(String userId);
    }
```

```
    public interface UserService <UserType extends User> {

        UserType create(String firstName, String lastName);

        void addConsent(UserType user, ConsentType consentType);
    }
```

As I mentioned earlier, current implementation of those interfaces is related to Mongo DB:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Document(collection = "user")
public class MongoUser extends AbstractMongoCollection implements User {

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    private List<PojoConsent> consents;

    private Boolean blocked;

    void addConsent(PojoConsent consent) {
        if(consents == null) {
            consents = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        consents.add(consent);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Consent> getConsents() {
        return new ArrayList<>(consents);
    }
}
```

```
@Component
public class MongoUserDao implements UserDao<MongoUser> {

    private MongoUserRepository mongoUserRepository;

    @Autowired
    public MongoUserDao(MongoUserRepository mongoUserRepository) {
        this.mongoUserRepository = mongoUserRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public MongoUser save(MongoUser user) {
        return mongoUserRepository.save(user);
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<MongoUser> getById(String userId) {
        return mongoUserRepository.findByIdAndDeletedIsFalse(userId);
    }
}
```

```
@Component
public class MongoUserService implements UserService<MongoUser> {

    private UserDao<MongoUser> userDao;

    @Autowired
    public MongoUserService(UserDao<MongoUser> userDao) {
        this.userDao = userDao;
    }

    @Override
    public MongoUser create(String firstName, String lastName) {
        MongoUser user = new MongoUser();
        user.setBlocked(false);
        user.setFirstName(firstName);
        user.setLastName(lastName);
        user.setDeleted(false);
        return userDao.save(user);
    }

    @Override
    public void addConsent(MongoUser user, ConsentType consentType) {
        PojoConsent pojoConsent = new PojoConsent();
        pojoConsent.setActive(true);
        pojoConsent.setType(consentType);
        pojoConsent.setDate(LocalDateTime.now());
        user.addConsent(pojoConsent);
        userDao.save(user);
    }
}
```

Ok, so what is the problem ? The problem occurs when I inject beans of type `UserDao` and `UserService` in other beans (as it happens in Spring Framework), like `EntryPoint` in this example (I'm aware of that there should be no logic in spring controller, but this is just an example):

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class EntryPoint {

    @Autowired
    private ConversationService conversationService;

    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;

    @PostMapping("/create/{userId}")
    public ResponseEntity<String> createConversation(@PathVariable("userId") String userId) {
        Optional<User> optionalUser = userDao.getById(userId);
        if(optionalUser.isPresent()) {
            User user = optionalUser.get();
            Conversation conversation = conversationService.create(user, "default");
            return ResponseEntity.ok(conversation.getId());
        }
        return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
    }
}
```

Interfaces `ConversationService` and `UserDao` have a generic type so warnings appear:

[image]
[image]

I don't want to give up generic types but on the other hand I'm aware that injecting without generic types will cause warnings which does not comply with clean code principles. It is true that this design will work despite warnings. I don't want to change implementation of the `EntryPoint` when I change persistence layer from MongoDb to JPA, I just want to provide new implementation for domain interfaces (`User`, `UserDao`, `UserService` etc.)

How to reconcile the interface issue for domain domain classes and injecting without generic type ?

Comment: Why does you need to use generic types ?

Comment: To avoid casting